# facebook login using oauth fails on live server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, oauth

I'm using OAuthWebSecurity to login with facebook and it is working on localhost. However then deployed to the live server I get the following error message:

The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

- I have checked domain details are correct on facebook.
- The sandbox mode is disabled.
- I have disabled windows firewall - still get same error.
- Responses from facebook have the identical format whether in live or localhost environments.
- The date and time of live server is correct.

I've test locally also changing the host file to the live domain - still works locally.

Here's the stack trace:

```
[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.]
System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request) +3291120
System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address) +207
DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients.FacebookClient.QueryAccessToken(Uri returnUrl, String authorizationCode) +293
DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients.OAuth2Client.VerifyAuthentication(HttpContextBase context, Uri returnPageUrl) +167
DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.OpenAuthSecurityManager.VerifyAuthentication(String returnUrl) +502
Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthenticationCore(HttpContextBase context, String returnUrl) +231
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please check facebook can be accessible on server or not. if not accessible then try to open facebook using browser

Comment: RDC to server, opened browser and was able to load and login to facebook no problem.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this? I'm encountering it for the first time now.

Answer (score 1):

There was a defect open related to this:
https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/issues/203

but that library is apparently no longer being maintained:
https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/issues/317#issuecomment-29580565

... although it is still referenced in many Microsoft documents. Investigating that related to another defect.

See also: [The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19433383/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-400-bad-request-microsoft-aspnet-membersh)

Comment: To an unenlightened outside observer, noting that the exact same defect showed up in a new Microsoft product with a similar feature set at the same time Microsoft abandoned the old open source project, it appears suspiciously like Microsoft incorporated this directly into a proprietary closed-source for-profit product.

Comment: What approach did you take to solving it?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old one, but I hit a 400 error from Facebook login using dotnetopenoath as it is integrated into MVC 4 and went on a wild goose chase thinking that it was not working because it was no longer supported, when all I needed to do was catch and log the exception which pointed me to the problem for my particular case (app secret proof setting):

```
catch (WebException exception)
{
    using (WebResponse response = exception.Response)
    {
        HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse) response;
        m_log.Debug("Error code: " + httpResponse.StatusCode);
        using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            if (data != null)
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(data))
                {
                    string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    m_log.Debug(text);
                }
             }
         }
    }
}
```