# The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth

Tags: facebook, dotnetopenauth

I'm using Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth when I create a new asp.net webform .net 4.0 and I config AuthConfig.cs:

```
OpenAuth.AuthenticationClients.AddFacebook(
                appId: "my appId",
                appSecret: "my appSecret");
```

In Facebook app config:
Website with Facebook Login: http://www.tindep.com

But when I login with facebook it's error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.]
   System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request) +283
   System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address) +100
   DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients.FacebookClient.QueryAccessToken(Uri returnUrl, String authorizationCode) +235
   DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients.OAuth2Client.VerifyAuthentication(HttpContextBase context, Uri returnPageUrl) +142
   DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.OpenAuthSecurityManager.VerifyAuthentication(String returnUrl) +239
   Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth.OpenAuthManager.VerifyAuthentication(HttpContextBase context, String returnUrl) +116
   Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth.OpenAuth.VerifyAuthentication(String returnUrl) +82
   EVNSoft.Website.Account.RegisterExternalLogin.ProcessProviderResult() +205
   EVNSoft.Website.Account.RegisterExternalLogin.Page_Load() +24
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +9808229
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18055
```

Although Google, Twitter, msdn login successful (Check tindep.com/Account/Login.aspx)
It's only error at hosting (tindep.com/Account/Login.aspx). localhost:57846/Account/Login.aspx login facebook success.

Please, help me find cause.

Thanks alot of!

Comment: Looking for this solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

There was a defect open related to this:
https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/issues/203

but that library is apparently no longer being maintained:
https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/issues/317#issuecomment-29580565

... although it is still referenced in many Microsoft documents. Investigating that related to another defect.

See also: [facebook login using oauth fails on live server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130000/facebook-login-using-oauth-fails-on-live-server)

Comment: To an unenlightened outside observer, noting that the exact same defect showed up in a new Microsoft product with a similar feature set at the same time Microsoft abandoned the old open source project, it appears suspiciously like Microsoft incorporated this directly into a proprietary closed-source for-profit product.